# Better way to exit for loop when using sync.WaitGroup?

Tags: go

Is there a better way to exit the for loop when using sync.WaitGroup? At the moment I am using bool e as a trigger to break out of the for loop at the end of the loop, which works. If I try to break the for loop where I check orders >= quantity I get all kinds of errors.

Is there a better way to break this loop than my bool code without causing panic?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var accounts int = 1
    var emails int = 1000

    for i := 0; i < accounts; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            threads := 500 //Max subroutines to run at once
            var orderMutex sync.Mutex
            var quantity = 2
            var orders = 0
            sem := make(chan bool, threads)
            var wgnested sync.WaitGroup

            var e = false

            for x := 0; x < emails; x++ {
                sem <- true //block

                orderMutex.Lock()
                if orders >= quantity {
                    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(x) + " Quantity Exceeded Stopping")
                    e = true
                }
                orderMutex.Unlock()

                wgnested.Add(1)

                go func() {
                    defer wgnested.Done()
                    defer func() { <-sem }()

                    //Simulate orders
                    if rand.Intn(50) == 7 {
                        orderMutex.Lock()
                        orders++
                        orderMutex.Unlock()
                    }

                    fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(i) + " Made to end ")

                }() //func

                if e {
                    break
                }
            } //x

            wgnested.Wait()

        loop:
            for {
                select {
                case <-sem:
                    fmt.Println("quit")
                    break loop
                default:
                    sem <- true
                }
            }
            fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(i) + " Orders: " + strconv.Itoa(orders))

        }(i)
    } //i

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use `context.Context` to stop a loop when the context is cancelled.

#### Example

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var (
        wg       sync.WaitGroup
        accounts int = 1
        emails   int = 1000
        //
        ctx, cancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background()) // create new context
    )

    for i := 0; i < accounts; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(i int) {
            // when goroutine finish
            // cancel the context
            defer func() {
                wg.Done()
                cancel()
            }()
            //
            var (
                // threads    = 500 //Max subroutines to run at once
                orderMutex sync.Mutex
                quantity   = 2
                orders     = 0
                wgnested   sync.WaitGroup
            )

            for x := 0; x < emails; x++ {
                select {
                // case context is done.
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    return
                default:
                    // check context is cancelled
                    // exit for loop
                    if ctx.Err() != nil {
                        return
                    }

                    orderMutex.Lock()
                    if orders >= quantity {
                        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(x) + " Quantity Exceeded Stopping")
                        cancel() // signal cancel context
                    }
                    orderMutex.Unlock()

                    wgnested.Add(1)
                    go func() {
                        defer wgnested.Done()

                        //Simulate orders
                        if rand.Intn(50) == 7 {
                            orderMutex.Lock()
                            orders++
                            orderMutex.Unlock()
                        }

                        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(x) + " Made to end ") // i used "x" instead of "i"

                    }()

                    wgnested.Wait()
                }
            }

            //
            fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(i) + " Orders: " + strconv.Itoa(orders))
        }(i)
    } //i

    wg.Wait()
}
```

#### Output

```
0 Made to end 
1 Made to end 
2 Made to end 
3 Made to end 
4 Made to end 
5 Made to end 
6 Made to end 
...
...
...
88 Made to end 
89 Made to end 
90 Made to end 
91 Made to end 
92 Made to end 
93 Made to end 
94 Quantity Exceeded Stopping
94 Made to end
```

Comment: I moved the ctx variable into the first loop and changed return to break in both areas of the code to receive the desired results. Thank you!

Comment: You removed the buffered channel that was limiting the concurrency.. can you help add it back?

Comment: Hey @NickD, thats where i was confused in your code. 
you can try this example: https://play.golang.org/p/6dqGr-FfbrG

I think there are better ways to limit threads than using channels. 

here in your original code. you are creating a new goroutine on every iteration. maybe you can limited the over all number of goroutine that access the loop.